# grunt serve: concurrent:server aborts due to warnings

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, gruntjs

suddenly my projects stops working with grunt. Unfortunately, I haven't committed my changes for a while into git, so I can't tell whats different.

When I run `grunt server --verbose`, I get the following output (everything above `...` passes with an `OK`):

```
...
Running "wiredep" task

Running "wiredep:app" (wiredep) task
Verifying property wiredep.app exists in config...OK
Files: app/index.html
Verifying property wiredep.app.src exists in config...OK

Running "wiredep:sass" (wiredep) task
Verifying property wiredep.sass exists in config...OK
Files: app/styles/analyzer.scss, app/styles/colors.scss, app/styles/login.scss, app/styles/main.scss, app/styles/shared.scss, app/styles/styles.scss, app/styles/tagsinput.scss
Verifying property wiredep.sass.src exists in config...OK

Running "concurrent:server" (concurrent) task
Verifying property concurrent.server exists in config...OK
Files: [no src] -> server
Options: limit=2
    Warning:  Use --force to continue.

        Aborted due to warnings.


Execution Time (2014-06-24 08:34:05 UTC)
loading tasks        8ms  0%
serve                2ms  0%
clean:server        10ms  0%
wiredep:app        242ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 4%
wiredep:sass        17ms  0%
concurrent:server   5.3s  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 95%
Total 5.6s
```

So, grunt aborts when trying to execute the task `concurrent:server`. Inside this task, the `compass:server` task is executed (see the `Gruntfile.js` below). So, it must have something todo with compass, but I'm not sure if this line `Files: [no src] -> server` could give more hints to the problem.

This is my `Gruntfile.js`:

```
// Generated on 2014-06-16 using generator-angular 0.9.0-1
'use strict';

// # Globbing
// for performance reasons we're only matching one level down:
// 'test/spec/{,*/}*.js'
// use this if you want to recursively match all subfolders:
// 'test/spec/**/*.js'

module.exports = function (grunt) {

  // Load grunt tasks automatically
  require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

  // Time how long tasks take. Can help when optimizing build times
  require('time-grunt')(grunt);

  // Configurable paths for the application
  var appConfig = {
    app: require('./bower.json').appPath || 'app',
    dist: 'dist'
  };

  // Define the configuration for all the tasks
  grunt.initConfig({

    // Project settings
    yeoman: appConfig,

    // Watches files for changes and runs tasks based on the changed files
    watch: {
      bower: {
        files: ['bower.json'],
        tasks: ['wiredep']
      },
      js: {
        files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'],
        tasks: [],
        options: {
          livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
        }
      },
      jsTest: {
        files: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.js'],
        tasks: ['newer:jshint:test', 'newer:jshint:all', 'karma']
      },
      compass: {
        files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}'],
        tasks: ['compass:server', 'autoprefixer'],
        options: {
            spawn: false,
        }
      },
      gruntfile: {
        files: ['Gruntfile.js']
      },
      livereload: {
        options: {
          livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
        },
        files: [
          '<%= yeoman.app %>/{,*/}*.html',
          '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/directives/**/*.html',
          '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css',
          '<%= yeoman.app %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}'
        ]
      }
    },

    // The actual grunt server settings
    connect: {
      options: {
        port: 9000,
        // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
        hostname: 'localhost',
        livereload: 35729
      },
      livereload: {
        options: {
          open: false,
          middleware: function (connect) {
            return [
              connect.static('.tmp'),
              connect().use(
                '/bower_components',
                connect.static('./bower_components')
              ),
              connect.static(appConfig.app)
            ];
          }
        }
      },
      test: {
        options: {
          port: 9001,
          middleware: function (connect) {
            return [
              connect.static('.tmp'),
              connect.static('test'),
              connect().use(
                '/bower_components',
                connect.static('./bower_components')
              ),
              connect.static(appConfig.app)
            ];
          }
        }
      },
      dist: {
        options: {
          open: false,
          base: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
        }
      }
    },

    // Make sure code styles are up to par and there are no obvious mistakes
    jshint: {
      options: {
        jshintrc: '.jshintrc',
        reporter: require('jshint-stylish')
      },
      all: {
        src: [
          'Gruntfile.js',
          '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js'
        ]
      },
      test: {
        options: {
          jshintrc: 'test/.jshintrc'
        },
        src: ['test/spec/{,*/}*.js']
      }
    },

    // Empties folders to start fresh
    clean: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          dot: true,
          src: [
            '.tmp',
            '<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*',
            '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/.git*'
          ]
        }]
      },
      server: '.tmp'
    },

    // Add vendor prefixed styles
    autoprefixer: {
      options: {
        browsers: ['last 1 version']
      },
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.tmp/styles/',
          src: '{,*/}*.css',
          dest: '.tmp/styles/'
        }]
      }
    },

    // Automatically inject Bower components into the app
    wiredep: {
      app: {
        src: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html'],
        ignorePath: new RegExp('^<%= yeoman.app %>/|../')
      },
      sass: {
        src: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}'],
        ignorePath: /(\.\.\/){1,2}bower_components\//
      }
    },

    // Compiles Sass to CSS and generates necessary files if requested
    compass: {
      options: {
        sassDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
        cssDir: '.tmp/styles',
        generatedImagesDir: '.tmp/images/generated',
        imagesDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
        javascriptsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts',
        fontsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/fonts',
        importPath: './bower_components',
        httpImagesPath: '/images',
        httpGeneratedImagesPath: '/images/generated',
        httpFontsPath: '/styles/fonts',
        relativeAssets: false,
        assetCacheBuster: false,
        raw: 'Sass::Script::Number.precision = 10\n'
      },
      dist: {
        options: {
          generatedImagesDir: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/generated'
        }
      },
      server: {
        options: {
          debugInfo: true
        }
      }
    },

    // Renames files for browser caching purposes
    filerev: {
      dist: {
        src: [
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css',
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}',
          '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/fonts/*'
        ]
      }
    },

    // Reads HTML for usemin blocks to enable smart builds that automatically
    // concat, minify and revision files. Creates configurations in memory so
    // additional tasks can operate on them
    useminPrepare: {
      html: '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html',
      options: {
        dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
        flow: {
          html: {
            steps: {
              js: ['concat', 'uglifyjs'],
              css: ['cssmin']
            },
            post: {}
          }
        }
      }
    },

    // Performs rewrites based on filerev and the useminPrepare configuration
    usemin: {
      html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*.html'],
      css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
      options: {
        assetsDirs: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>','<%= yeoman.dist %>/images']
      }
    },

    // The following *-min tasks will produce minified files in the dist folder
    // By default, your `index.html`'s <!-- Usemin block --> will take care of
    // minification. These next options are pre-configured if you do not wish
    // to use the Usemin blocks.
    // cssmin: {
    //   dist: {
    //     files: {
    //       '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/main.css': [
    //         '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css'
    //       ]
    //     }
    //   }
    // },
    // uglify: {
    //   dist: {
    //     files: {
    //       '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js': [
    //         '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/scripts.js'
    //       ]
    //     }
    //   }
    // },
    // concat: {
    //   dist: {}
    // },

    imagemin: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
          src: '{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif}',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
        }]
      }
    },

    svgmin: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
          src: '{,*/}*.svg',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
        }]
      }
    },

    htmlmin: {
      dist: {
        options: {
          collapseWhitespace: true,
          conservativeCollapse: true,
          collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
          removeCommentsFromCDATA: true,
          removeOptionalTags: true
        },
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
          src: ['*.html', 'views/{,*/}*.html'],
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
        }]
      }
    },

    // ngmin tries to make the code safe for minification automatically by
    // using the Angular long form for dependency injection. It doesn't work on
    // things like resolve or inject so those have to be done manually.
    ngmin: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.tmp/concat/scripts',
          src: '*.js',
          dest: '.tmp/concat/scripts'
        }]
      }
    },

    // Replace Google CDN references
    cdnify: {
      dist: {
        html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/*.html']
      }
    },

    // Copies remaining files to places other tasks can use
    copy: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          dot: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
          src: [
            '*.{ico,png,txt}',
            '.htaccess',
            '*.html',
            'views/{,*/}*.html',
            'images/{,*/}*.{webp}',
            'fonts/*'
          ]
        }, {
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.tmp/images',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images',
          src: ['generated/*']
        }, {
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.',
          src: 'bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/fonts/bootstrap/*',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
        }]
      },
      styles: {
        expand: true,
        cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
        dest: '.tmp/styles/',
        src: '{,*/}*.css'
      }
    },

    // Run some tasks in parallel to speed up the build process
    concurrent: {
      server: [
        'compass:server'
      ],
      test: [
        'compass'
      ],
      dist: [
        'compass:dist',
        'imagemin',
        'svgmin'
      ]
    },

    // Test settings
    karma: {
      unit: {
        configFile: 'test/karma.conf.js',
        singleRun: false
      }
    }
  });


  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-sass');

  grunt.registerTask('serve', 'Compile then start a connect web server', function (target) {
    if (target === 'dist') {
      return grunt.task.run(['build', 'connect:dist:keepalive']);
    }
    grunt.task.run([
      'clean:server',
      'wiredep',
      'concurrent:server',
      'autoprefixer',
      'connect:livereload',
      'watch'
    ]);
  });

  grunt.registerTask('server', 'DEPRECATED TASK. Use the "serve" task instead', function (target) {
    grunt.log.warn('The `server` task has been deprecated. Use `grunt serve` to start a server.');
    grunt.task.run(['serve:' + target]);
  });

  grunt.registerTask('test', [
    'clean:server',
    'autoprefixer',
    'connect:test',
    'karma'
  ]);

  grunt.registerTask('build', [
    'clean:dist',
    'wiredep',
    'useminPrepare',
    'concurrent:dist',
    'autoprefixer',
    'concat',
    'ngmin',
    'copy:dist',
    'cdnify',
    'cssmin',
    'uglify',
    'filerev',
    'usemin',
    'htmlmin'
  ]);

  grunt.registerTask('default', [
    'newer:jshint',
    'test',
    'build'
  ]);
};
```

I generated the project with the yo angular generator. And this is my environment:

- `node -v: v0.10.25`
- `ruby -v: ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [x86_64-darwin13.0]`
- `yo -v: 1.1.2`
- `gem list:`

  *** LOCAL GEMS ***

  bigdecimal (1.2.4)
  bundler (1.6.2)
  bundler-unload (1.0.2)
  chunky_png (1.3.1)
  compass (0.12.6)
  executable-hooks (1.3.1)
  fssm (0.2.10)
  gem-wrappers (1.2.4)
  io-console (0.4.2)
  json (1.8.1)
  minitest (4.7.5)
  psych (2.0.5)
  rake (10.1.0)
  rdoc (4.1.0)
  rubygems-bundler (1.4.3)
  rvm (1.11.3.9)
  sass (3.3.8, 3.2.19)
  test-unit (2.1.2.0)
- `grunt --verison: grunt-cli v0.1.13, grunt v0.4.5`
- Mac OS X 10.9

This is my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "project1",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "^0.4.1",
    "grunt-autoprefixer": "^0.7.3",
    "grunt-concurrent": "^0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "^0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-coffee": "^0.10.1",
    "grunt-contrib-compass": "~0.8.0",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "^0.4.0",
    "grunt-contrib-connect": "^0.7.1",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "^0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "^0.9.0",
    "grunt-contrib-htmlmin": "^0.3.0",
    "grunt-contrib-imagemin": "^0.7.0",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "^0.10.0",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "^0.4.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^0.6.1",
    "grunt-filerev": "^0.2.1",
    "grunt-google-cdn": "^0.4.0",
    "grunt-newer": "^0.7.0",
    "grunt-ngmin": "^0.0.3",
    "grunt-svgmin": "^0.4.0",
    "grunt-usemin": "^2.1.1",
    "grunt-wiredep": "^1.7.0",
    "jshint-stylish": "^0.2.0",
    "load-grunt-tasks": "^0.4.0",
    "time-grunt": "^0.3.1",
    "coffee-script": "~1.7.1",
    "grunt-karma": "~0.8.3",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "~0.1.4",
    "karma": "~0.12.16",
    "karma-jasmine": "~0.1.5",
    "karma-coffee-preprocessor": "~0.2.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~0.1.4",
    "karma-script-launcher": "~0.1.0",
    "karma-firefox-launcher": "~0.1.3",
    "karma-safari-launcher": "~0.1.1",
    "karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor": "~0.1.0",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "~0.2.2",
    "grunt-ng-constant": "~0.5.0",
    "grunt-bowercopy": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage": "~0.2.4",
    "grunt-protractor-runner": "~1.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-given": "~0.1.1",
    "grunt-sass": "~0.13.1"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.10.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "grunt test"
  }
}
```

And this is my `bower.json`:

```
{
  "name": "project1",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "1.3.0-beta.11",
    "json3": "~3.3.1",
    "es5-shim": "~3.1.0",
    "jquery": "~1.11.1",
    "bootstrap-sass-official": "~3.1.1",
    "bootstrap": "~3.1.1",
    "angular-resource": "1.3.0-beta.11",
    "angular-cookies": "1.3.0-beta.11",
    "angular-sanitize": "1.3.0-beta.11",
    "angular-animate": "1.3.0-beta.11",
    "angular-touch": "1.3.0-beta.11",
    "angular-route": "1.3.0-beta.11",
    "font-awesome": "~4.1",
    "underscore": "~1.6.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "1.3.0-beta.11",
    "angular-scenario": "1.3.0-beta.11"
  },
  "appPath": "app"
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Stupid me!

For anybody encountering the same issue:

I had some import errors in my SCSS files. During the live reload of grunt, it would tell you that there is something wrong. But during the startup of `grunt serve` it just breaks and tells you nothing. So, check your imports and syntax of your SCSS files.

Comment: I have the same problem. I works on one machine and fails on the other (due to warnings). Any suggestions?

Comment: To isloate the problem, check if you have some SCSS problems. Comment out every SCSS and start your server. If the server doesn't start, it should be not SCSS syntax related. If it does start, comment in every SCSS statement step by step. Now you get proper errors / warnings on your file, and you can fix it.

Comment: It had to do with the sass gem version. We had a compilation problems with version 3.4.0, which we didn't have with 3.3.14.

Comment: Run `grunt compass` to see where the compilation fails.

Comment: I upgraded my grunt-concurrent 1.0.0->2.1.1 and there errors are now propagated up on grunt server-start.

Comment: well, I ran into the same issue and ended up spending couple of hours. I learned it could happen due to 2 reasons. 
#1. due to wrong syntax in .sccs files(s). 
#2. due to wrong path set for `compass->options->importPath` in your `Gruntfile.js` in this case, the path should look something similar to `'<%= yeoman.app %>/bower_components'` depending on the structure of project.

Answer (score 4):

It's import in SCSS files.  Try

```
grunt serve --force
```

This may force the build process to continue even though your SCSS fails to compile.  The end result is you'll start the grunt server and it'll tell you exactly where the build process failed.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, my SCSS has no grammar faults, this happened because I installed compass globally (`npm -g`), while it needed to be installed as a Ruby gem:

```
gem install compass
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not an expert but I find that once the local server is running it will allow lint errors in scss or whatever, then once you stop the server and try to restart it will give this error until you fix the scss errors. You can use grunt check and then just resolve them and try again. 9/10 this is why my server wont restart.