# grunt build Aborted due to warning "Destination not written because minified HTML was empty" and "Parse Error:"

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, yeoman

I am using Yeoman (http://yeoman.io/) and I usually just run

```
grunt build
```

in order to minify and upload my AngularJS app to the server. However for some reason I am getting a

```
  >> Destination not written because minified HTML was empty.
```

I haven't had this trouble before until now and I have not changed my Grunt file. It seems as though everything else is getting minifies just fine, even the other html files within the same /views directory. I read on this thread ([grunt serve: concurrent:server aborts due to warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24382098/grunt-serve-concurrentserver-aborts-due-to-warnings)) about something with SCSS but I can't seem to pin point the issue. Why can't I minify my dsit/views/main.html? Here is what it looks like in the terminal

```
  Running "htmlmin:dist" (htmlmin) task
  Minified dist/404.html 3.53 kB → 3.39 kB
  Minified dist/index.html 2.5 kB → 2.31 kB
  Minified dist/views/about.html 31 B → 30 B
  >> Destination not written because minified HTML was empty.
  Minified dist/views/explore.html 33 B → 32 B
  Warning: dist/views/main.html
  Parse Error: <a ng-click="nextCampaign()" class"nav-button">
      <i class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-2x"></i>
    </a>
  </nav>......... more code
```

Here is the "htmlmin:dist" in my Grunt file that is giving me the error

```
  htmlmin: {
  dist: {
    options: {
      collapseWhitespace: true,
      conservativeCollapse: true,
      collapseBooleanAttributes: true,
      removeCommentsFromCDATA: true,
      removeOptionalTags: true
    },
    files: [{
      expand: true,
      cwd: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
      src: ['*.html', 'views/{,*/}*.html'],
      dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
    }]
  }
},
```

Here is the main.html component it is complaining about

```
  Parse Error: <a ng-click="nextCampaign()" class"nav-button">
      <i class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-2x"></i>
    </a>
  </nav>

  <nav class="modal-previous hidden-mobile">
    <a ng-click="previousCampaign()"class"nav-button">
      <i class="fa fa-chevron-left fa-2x"></i>
    </a>
  </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. It was just a simple error, I left out a "=" in between

```
 class"nav-button"
```

I simply changed it to

```
class="nav-button"
```

and everything was all good. If you ever get this error, check the line that the terminal tells you that there is a

```
 Parse Error: ...html...
```

Sometimes it is just that simple.